# How can I terminate EMR cluster when a step generated undesirable results in s3

Tags: java, amazon-emr, amazon-swf

My Amazon Simple workflow spins an EMR cluster and adds some steps which depends on the output of the preceding step. If i have 10 steps and say my 6th step generates output in s3 which should be looked by 7th step to determine if the step can continue further or terminate the cluster based on the 6th step output. My work flow runs fine, but how do I terminate the cluster if the output is undesired. I am using AWS java sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you identify the problem, use code as below to terminate the cluster

You might have used below code to launch cluster

```
AmazonElasticMapReduce emr=new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(
.

.

// Run the job flow
 RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request)

//shutdown when you notice any error

 emr.shutdown();
```